# InfluxDB: Query From Multiple Series

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have an influxdb instance, in which an upstream server is logging measurements into. I have multiple series of the shape: `web.[domain].[status]`, for example: `web.www.foobar.com.2xx`, `web.www.quux.com.3xx` etc. There are two "variables" encoded into the series name: the domain and the status (`2xx`, `3xx`, etc. are already aggregated).

Now I'd like to see how many of those requests I get. One possibility would be to just list the series:

`select sum("value") from "web.www.quux.com.2xx","web.www.quux.com.3xx",...`

But this is neither practical (too many) nor actually feasible (new domains are added and removed all the time), so I need a more flexible approach.

Is there some kind of wildcard syntax allowed in the `from` clause? The documentation doesn't mention any. Or is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to avoid this kind of measurement naming convention:

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#avoid-encoding-data-in-measurement-names

> hAvoid encoding data in measurement names
>
> InfluxDB queries merge data that falls within the same measurement; it’s better to differentiate data with tags than with detailed measurement names. If you encode data in a measurement name, you must use a regular expression to query the data, making some queries more complicated or impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, which sounds very reasonable to me. However, there's already some upstream data I need to handle to begin with.

Comment: @PatrickBucher I would switch to correct structure and then "copy" old data to new correct structure, so you won't loose any data. If you can't do that then regexp can be used https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#regular-expressions

Comment: I think converting the data is the better way forward. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: I now use tags properly, which allows me to select the measurements properly. It required me to learn a bit of Clojure, since the data is ingested via Riemann. But it was worth it!